# Trying to make my first gem and installation isn't working correctly

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've written a gem and have installed it, despite this gem which does not find the gem, nor does require 'gem_name'

Here is my gemspec

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'faker/faker-rpg/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "faker-rpg"
  spec.version       = Faker::Rpg::VERSION
  spec.authors       = [""]
  spec.email         = [""]
  spec.summary       = ""
  spec.description   = ""
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.5"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

gem list does find the gem

```
gem list faker-rpg

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

faker-rpg (0.0.1)
```

It is definitely installed to the gem folder

```
ls /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/ | grep faker-rpg

faker-rpg-0.0.1
```

And this is the file structure of faker-rpg-0.0.1 inside the above gems folder

```
ls -R

Gemfile     Rakefile
LICENSE.txt   faker-rpg.gemspec
README.md   lib

./lib:
faker locales

./lib/faker:
faker-rpg faker-rpg.rb

./lib/faker/faker-rpg:
version.rb

./lib/locales:
faker.en.yml
```

gem which won't find the gem

```
gem which faker-rpg

ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library faker-rpg
```

In the ruby console require won't work

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > require 'faker-rpg'

LoadError: cannot load such file -- faker-rpg
```

And here is what gem spec faker-rpg gives

```
gem spec faker-rpg

--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification
name: faker-rpg
version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version
  version: 0.0.1
platform: ruby
authors:
- ''
autorequire: 
bindir: bin
cert_chain: []
date: 2014-06-25 00:00:00.000000000 Z
dependencies:
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: bundler
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.5'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.5'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rake
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - '>='
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - '>='
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0'
description: ''
email:
- ''
executables: []
extensions: []
extra_rdoc_files: []
files: []
homepage: ''
licenses:
- MIT
metadata: {}
post_install_message: 
rdoc_options: []
require_paths:
- lib
required_ruby_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
  requirements:
  - - '>='
    - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
      version: '0'
required_rubygems_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
  requirements:
  - - '>='
    - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
      version: '0'
requirements: []
rubyforge_project: 
rubygems_version: 2.2.2
signing_key: 
specification_version: 4
summary: ''
test_files: []
```

I've found multiple questions about this, and none of the answers that were accepted solved my problem.
The only thing I can think of is that gemspec has the line 'files: []' but the files are definitely in the gem installed to the gems folder.

Does anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem is actually installed correctly, it’s just you haven’t got your lib paths quite right. Try running `gem which faker/faker-rpg` to see.

You just need to move the contents of `lib/faker` up a level, so that they are directly under `lib`. Currently you are searching for `faker-rpg.rb`, but that file only exists as `faker/faker-rpg.rb`, so it isn’t being found.

You’ll probably need to adjust some other parts to make it all work. You don’t mention what is in the `locales` directory – it might be better to move that under the `faker-rpg` directory as well. Also the `require` line in your `gemspec` where you get the version will need to be adjusted.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Just needed to move those files directly under lib. Moving Locales fixed another problem I was having as well, thanks a bunch.